# Can't use `-Z macro-backtrace` unstable option with `cargo`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, nightly-build, rustup

I am writing rust macros and came across an error about my macro I can't understand. In hope of understanding it better, I tried to follow the compiler's advice by setting the `-Z macro-backtrace` unstable option and compiling again. Here is said advice:

```
note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

But doing this:

```
cargo run -Z macro-backtrace
```

Results in this:

```
error: unknown `-Z` flag specified: macro-backtrace
```

I already switched to the nightly toolchain entirely by running `rustup override nightly` in the project directory and `rustup default nightly` for future uses of this feature, but still the error presists.

In diggin through the web, I found a way to list all `-Z` options with `cargo -Z help`:

```
Available unstable (nightly-only) flags:

    -Z avoid-dev-deps   -- Avoid installing dev-dependencies if possible
    -Z minimal-versions -- Install minimal dependency versions instead of maximum
    -Z no-index-update  -- Do not update the registry, avoids a network request for benchmarking
    -Z unstable-options -- Allow the usage of unstable options
    -Z timings          -- Display concurrency information
    -Z doctest-xcompile -- Compile and run doctests for non-host target using runner config
    -Z terminal-width   -- Provide a terminal width to rustc for error truncation

Run with 'cargo -Z [FLAG] [SUBCOMMAND]'

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html for more information about these flags.
```

No `-Z macro-backtrace`... I went to the specified link, butr even there a search for `macro-backtrace` yields no results.

So I am stuck... I would pretty much like to use this feature and yet can't seem to find a way to activate it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`-Z macro-backtrace` is a `rustc` flag, not a `cargo` flag. You should be able to pass it to `rustc` using `cargo +nightly rustc -- -Z macro-backtrace`. (The `+nightly` in the command line is optional if you already switched to the nightly compiler as the default.)

Alternatively, you can set the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable:

```
export RUSTFLAGS="-Z macro-backtrace"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. It would be nice if the error message mentioned this...

Comment: I would recommend using it like so: `RUSTFLAGS="-Z macro-backtrace" cargo ...` however, it does not pollute the env. variables